# Increased Version and Build but still key CFBundleVersion Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously uploaded version

Tags: xcode, info.plist

My app is in the store with Version 2013.0 (I opted to use the year) and Build 1.

Trying to update, even tried Version 3000 Build 5.

Continue to receive error message: "This bundle is invalid. The key CF BundleVersion in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously uploaded version."

I've read the various answers to solve this problem - what I did should work.

Any suggestions? xCode 4.5.2

TIA